# Why the typing lag after interaction with a 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, front-end, keyboard, interactive

[Mathematica 12.1 on Windows 10 64-bit. My `Antialiasing Quality` is set to `No Antialiasing`]

**Edit:** the behaviour is actually more erratic than described below. It seems that the front-end becomes randomly unresponsive when 3D plots are in the *visible* area of the notebook...

**Update:** After some testing, it seems that the lag is related to the `UndoOptions`. After setting `"MaxLength`" to `2` and "`RememberEvaluations`" to `False`, the lag seems to have disappeared. Possibly Mathematica was saving the full plot as shown from the previous ViewPoint?, In case I wanted to undo the my plot manipulation?

Mathematica is showing this annoying behaviour:

Suppose I interact (eg rotate) with a 3D plot in an output cell. Then, if I type (or delete or select with the mouse) in the corresponding input cell, there is a huge lag – even 5 seconds – before I see the results of my typing.

To explain better: imagine I type this in a new cell:

`Plot3D[x^3 + y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]`

the typing has no lag. I press `shif+enter` and I see the corresponding 3D plot in the output cell.

Now I go back to the input cell and type to modify it – eg deleting `3` and typing `2` in its place. The typing has *no* lag. I press again `shif+enter` and I get an updated plot in the output cell.

I can repeat this process many times. There's no typing lag.

Now suppose instead that, after pressing `shif+enter`, I *interact* with the plot in the output cell (eg, rotate it with the mouse). If I now go back to the input cell to modify its text, say deleting `3` and typing `2`, I experience a lag of several seconds before the `3` disappears, and before the `2` appears.

Note that if I type on a *new* input cell, there is *no* lag.

How come this strange behaviour? Is it a bug? Or can it be avoided by changing some settings?

Thank you!

Comment: I tried what you said. I didn't experience lag. (+) What if, you right-click, reset default view? Still, lags then? Though, not what you said, I understand.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. No change. But I'm doing some more testing and the behaviour seems more erratic than I thought.